# Update property value in nested array (redux state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How do you update a certain nested property in redux state?

Let's say I only want to update the "value" property in the object below. I know you shouldn't deep copy the previous state but how do i only change the property of an object in an array in an object of an array?

Thanks in advance!

```js
market {
  shops: [
    {
      name: 'abc',
      items: [
        {
          name: 'item1',
          value: 40,
          id: '234rfds32'
        },
        {}
      ]
    },
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

Something like the following:

```js
state = {
  ...state, 
  shops: [
    ...state.shops,
    shops[index].items = [
      ...shops[index].items,
    ]
  ]
};
```

Comment: `market.shops[0].items[0].value = 10` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Thanks for the fast reply but no, i updated the post to make it more clear what I'm looking for. I want to update the state with only the "value" property changed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work. (code looks ugly, didn't test though)

```
var shop =  state.shops[index];
var items = [...shop.items];
items[<index>].value = 'your value';
shop.items = items;
var shops = [...state.shops];
shops[index] = shop;

state = {
...state, 
shops 
};
```